# laravel - How to get data by pivot table

Tags: mysql, laravel, pdo, model

I have a problem with laravel. I have created relationships between tables and relationships at the model level in laravel but if I want to display data to the view, I get an error: **Property [category] does not exist on this collection instance.**

the table with the films is called: videos

the table with the categories is called: categories

the pivot table is called: category_video

**Video model code:**

```
public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category');
}
```

**Categories model code:**

```
public function videos()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Video');
}
```

**In controller i have this:**

```
$slider_videos = Video::->orderBy('rating','desc')
    ->limit(5)
    ->get();
```

**In view i try this:**

```
@foreach($slider_videos as $slider_video)
    {{$slider_video->category->name}}
@endforeach
```

I will add that when I use this: `{{$slider_video->category}}` it's displaying all contents of single row

By the way, how can I specify the name of the pivot table in the model?

Comment: Second parametr in **belongsToMany** is pivot table name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Categories are a collection you need to loop over it :

```
@foreach($slider_videos as $slider_video)
    {{ $slider_videos->name }} categories are : 
    @foreach($slider_video->categories as $category)
        {{$category->name}}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

`belongsToMany` returns a collection even if there is only a single record linked with the relationship.
You need to access it in a `foreach` loop.
Like so.

```
@foreach($slider_video->categories as $category)
    {{$category->>field_name}}
@endforeach
```